# SwiftUI ZStack alignment works strangely

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created very simple views with SwiftUI including ZStack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Text("aaa")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
        .frame(width: 142.0, height: 142.0)
        .background(.pink)
    }
}
```

I expected that the Text("aaa") would appear in the top leading of pink square.

But the result was this.

[image: ZStack without Color.clear]

More strangely, it works well if I add 'Color.clear' to ZStack like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.clear
            Text("aaa")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
        .frame(width: 142.0, height: 142.0)
        .background(.pink)
    }
}
```

And the result it this.

[image: ZStack with Color.clear]

I cannot understand this situation. SwiftUI is totally crazy.

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of the `ZStack` are laid out and aligned based on the size of the **largest child**, not the frame of the `ZStack` itself.
You should think of the "content area" of the stack being seperate to the frame of the stack.

When you add a `Color.clear`, its default frame is unbounded (the height and width are `infinity`), so when it is added to the `ZStack`, it will grow the "content area" to the maximum possible size.
This makes the content area of the stack the same size as the `ZStack`s frame.

You can achieve the same result (in a clearer way) by using a `Spacer()` with explicit infinite bounds.
This will ensure the children always fill the same available to them.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Spacer()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            Text("aaa")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
        .frame(width: 142.0, height: 142.0)
        .background(.pink)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh...I see. I didn't know the concept of the "content area" at all. Thank you very much!